# What is the bond energy of Carbon-Deuterium bond?

Tags: energy, hydrocarbons

The difference in bond strength of a CH single bond and CD single bond can be explained by Kinetic Isotope Effect. I was wondering if it is possible by bond energy. I could not find the value of bond strength of CD bond. For CH bond it is 410. What is the energy for CD bond? Experimental data if available is appreciated.

Comment: related: [Would C bond with H or D?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24743/would-c-bond-with-h-or-d)

Comment: i guess it comes out to be 3.52 eV (3.51673, was the cited value), btw, heres the link:-http://www.millsian.com/summarytables/SummaryTables022709S.pdf

Comment: Bond strength is the same as bond energy. To explain one by the other is equivalent to saying _"this bond is stronger, because, well, it has more strength"_.

Comment: @Supernova the table gave the information required.

Comment: @YAHB, glad it helped...!!!